# Unable to access REST API services provided Spark Server Web UI in Bitnami Spark Docker Image

Tags: docker, rest, apache-spark, bitnami

According to the official Spark documentation, it stated that the running Spark applications have REST endpoints accessible through the web UI url and a JSON response would be returned [Spark REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api).

However, when I tried to access these endpoints, I keep getting redirected back to the default monitoring page. I'm unsure if I might be doing something incorrectly, or it might be because the creators of this image did not implement this feature. On the official bitnami/spark docker page, there is limited information regarding the configuring and availability of these REST APIs [Screen shot of default monitoring page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aclP.png)

Edited

[Screenshot of the port mapping in docker compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEkLA.png)

Comment: Can you please provide link behind - application URL?
Just wanted to confirm if port is matching with exposed port in docker.

Comment: Hi @fly2matrix, thanks for your help. Added the screen shot of the port mappings in my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the docker-compose file. However I am looking html url inside the page (worker ID or Application ID):

Comment: @fly2matrix I am not if this is what you're looking for, but upon clicking on the url of the worker it brings me to http://172.18.0.11:8081/

Comment: @fly2matrix Clicking on the url of the application brings me to http://localhost:7000/app/?appId=app-20230613084507-0003